# Kinect for Windows with Processing and SimpleOpenNI on Apple OSX stops working after 20 sec

Tags: macos, kinect, processing, openni, simple-openni

I am using Kinect for Windows (not for XBOX) on Apple iMac 3GHz 4GB 10.8.3. The Kinect is connected with USB cable to iMac and with power supply.

Software: I have installed XCode, XQuartz, MaxPorts, CMake, then libtool, libusb, OpenNI SDK v1.5.4.0, SensorKinect, and NiTE v1.5.2.21.

I am running Processing 2.0.8 with SimpleOpenNI 0.27 library.

Any example from SimpleOpenNI runs, but after approximatly 20sec Kinect stops working and freezes.
(I need to say that the green led is blinking constantly but Kinect is still working, since at least for short period time I can get e.g. the depth image etc.)

Any ideas why is not working constantly? Maybe I need Kinect for Xbox in the end? Is there any power supply issues with Apple computer? (I have tested the same Kinect device on PC and it worked fine)

Comment: I used [these instructions](http://decyborg.wordpress.com/2013/01/19/kinect-on-os-x-10-8-and-processing/) to get up and running and face the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late, but for others finding this problem that I also found, try installing OpenKinect within Processing and running one of the sample sketches (like Average Point Tracking) for a moment, closing, then trying your Simple OpenNI sketch. I'm also using .27 (because I couldn't get later versions to work) and this fixes the problem, but you have to do it every time you plug the camera back in or restart the OS. Hope this helps someone else.